# Could not load type 'SAS.LanguageServiceCarriageControl' from assembly

Tags: c#, sas

In addition to using the integration components of SAS Enterprise Edition, I am using parts of the following project I found on Github to connect with a SAS server. The goal here is to command the server to run programs on a schedule. However, the programs need to be modified each time, which is why I am attempting to trigger them to run in this manner. However, it keeps throwing an error at lang.FlushLogLines.

https://github.com/cjdinger/SasHarness

```
SAS.Workspace ws = server.Workspace;
List<string> results = new List<string>();
Array CCs;
Array lineTypes;
Array logLines;
int maxLines = 100;
SAS.LanguageService lang = (SAS.LanguageService)ws.LanguageService;
Array linesVar = (Array)new string[] { PROGRAM_TEXT };
lang.SubmitLines(ref linesVar);

//THROWS AN ERROR HERE
lang.FlushLogLines(maxLines, out CCs, out lineTypes, out logLines);

for (int i = 0; i < logLines.Length; i++)
{
    results.Add((string)logLines.GetValue(i));
}
```

After a bit of research I found the following thread where it is recommended to make sure that all the required dlls are referenced in my project. The mystery here is that I do have them referenced, but the error still occurs.

http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/06/09/sas-client-with-microsoft-dot-net/

Moreover, starting after the very first line, the code is no longer using SASHarness, but is using native SAS integration libraries only. The code above is also based on examples listed in the following documentation from SAS.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/itechwcdg/61500/PDF/default/itechwcdg.pdf (page 27-28)

Has anybody encountered an error similar to this, and if so, how did you correct it?

Comment: Post at communities.sas.com and the author of the code - Chris Hemedinger will possibly respond.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Thank you. Chris is very good at responding but give me Stack Overflow over communities.sas.com any day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely, fixing this error required declaring an instance for each of the assemblies that could not be loaded. I have no idea why this fixes the problem, but it works now.

```
SAS.Workspace ws = server.Workspace;
string wsId = ws.UniqueIdentifier;

List<string> results = new List<string>();
Array CCs;
Array lineTypes;
Array logLines;
int maxLines = 100;
SAS.LanguageService lang = (SAS.LanguageService) server.Workspace.LanguageService;
Array linesVar = (Array) new string[] { PROGRAM_TEXT };

lang.SubmitLines(ref linesVar);

//For some reason, these two declarations need to be here
SAS.LanguageServiceCarriageControl CarriageControl = new SAS.LanguageServiceCarriageControl();
SAS.LanguageServiceLineType LineType = new SAS.LanguageServiceLineType();

lang.FlushLogLines(maxLines, out CCs, out lineTypes, out logLines);
for (int i = 0; i < logLines.Length; i++)
{
    results.Add((string) logLines.GetValue(i));
}
```

Comment: I needed to reference the instance later on to stop VS clearing it.   i.e.     CarriageControl.ToString();
LineType.ToString();

Comment: What do you mean? Why would you need to use the "ToString()" function?

Comment: If I don't reference the instance later I get the original error.